# Problem to animate a 3D object on a path with three.js

Tags: three.js, path

I am learning three.js and I am looking to make an animation of a 3D object that is a bee. This bee already contains an animation that is a flutter of wings. My goal is to make this bee travel from image to image as the scroll down .
I want to make this animation in pure three.js without libraries such as Tween.js

I can import this 3D object (bee) in the upper part of the viewport. But the problem is that it disappears as soon as the vertical scroll starts.

my files are:

HTML

```
<body>
    <canvas class="webgl"></canvas>
    <nav>
      <div class="left">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <i class="fa-regular fa-user"></i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <header class="section">
      <h1>ABEILLES</h1>
      <h2>7 preuves que les abeilles vont sauver le monde</h2>
    </header>
    <main>
      <section class="section intro">
     
        <img src="./static/Tournesol2.png" id="f1" alt="fleur de Tournesol avec un escargot">
        <p>
          La plupart du temps, ces petites fées butinent les fleurs dans
          l’indifférence générale. Pourtant, elles sauvent régulièrement la
          planète sans masque ni super pouvoir. La preuve par ces sept exploits.
        </p>
      </section>

      <section class="section odd">
        <img src="/static/izumi.png" id="f2" alt="fleurs jaunes et violettes">
          <div class="text">
            <h3>01</h3>
            <h4>Les abeilles remplissent notre assiette au quotidien</h4>
            <p>
            Nous devons aux abeilles un tiers de notre nourriture et de celle
            des animaux. Les abeilles font vivre l'écosystème en permettant la
            reproduction de certaines plantes, grâce à leur remarquable travail
            de pollinisation.
            </p>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section class="section even">
        <div class="text">
          <h3>02</h3>
          <h4>Les abeilles : véritables détecteurs de mines</h4>
          <p>
            En Croatie, une armée d'abeilles démineuses rigoureusement entraînée
            sauve des vies grâce à leurs facultés olfactives puissantes. Elles
            peuvent en effet renifler des odeurs à 4,5 km de distance.
          </p>
        </div>
        <img src="/static/feuilles.png" id="f3"  alt="Feuilles">
      </section>

      <section class="section odd">
        <img class="rose" src="/static/rose.png" id="f4" alt="Rose">
        <div class="text">
          <h3>03</h3>
          <h4>Le miel : une douceur aux multiples vertus</h4>
          <p>
            Les abeilles offrent un précieux nectar aux vertus multiples. Outre
            son arôme et son goût sucré, le miel peut avoir plusieurs utilités.
            Il révèle le taux de pollution et la présence d'hydrocarbure sur les
            lieux où évoluent les abeilles.
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="section even">
        <div class="text">
          <h3>04</h3>
          <h4>Le venin a un pouvoir guérisseur</h4>
          <p>
            Régulièrement utilisé en acupuncture, le venin d'abeille rend un
            beau service. Malgré l'absence de preuves scientifiques, la thérapie
            par le venin est populaire chez les personnes atteintes de douleurs
            musculosquelettiques. En effet, le venin d'abeille aurait un pouvoir
            analgésique et anti-inflammatoire qui permettrait de soulager les
            douleurs aux articulations.
          </p>
        </div>
        <img class="pansy" src="/static/pansy.png" id="f5" alt="Pansy">
      </section>

      <section class="section odd">
        <img class="shabeer" src="/static/shabeer.png" id="f6" alt="une abeille sur une fleur">
        <div class="text">
          <h3>05</h3>
          <h4>La cire d'abeille : multifonctionnelle !</h4>
          <p>
            Une ruche regorge de cire. Cette substance jaune, vendue sous
            différentes formes, en lotion ou même en baume à lèvres, nous rend
            bien des services au quotidien. Son épaisseur et ses agents
            protecteurs en font un allié solide :
          </p>
          <ul>
            <li>Elle hydrate la peau.</li>
            <li>Elle apaise les gerçures et les irritations de l'épiderme.</li>
            <li>Elle protège du froid et du vent.</li>
            <li>Elle accélère la cicatrisation.</li>
            <li>Elle combat les inflammations.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="section even">
        <div class="text">
          <h3>06</h3>
          <h4>La gelée royale sauve des vies</h4>
          <p>
            La gelée royale, produite en grande quantité dans la ruche,
            contribue à prévenir un certain nombre de maladies graves. Riche en
            vitamines et en sucre, la gelée royale aide à lutter contre :
          </p>
          <ul>
            <li>le cancer</li>
            <li>le cholestérol</li>
            <li>l’hypertension</li>
            <li>l'insuffisance cardiaque</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <img class="tournesol" src="/static/Tournesol.png" id="f7"  alt="Tournesol">
      </section>

      <section class="section odd">
        <img src="/static/becOiseaux2.png" id="f8"  alt="Fleur exotique 'bec d'oiseaux">
        <div class="text">
          <h3>07</h3>
          <h4>La propolis : contre la douleur et les maladies</h4>
          <p>
            La propolis est une résine végétale fabriquée par les abeilles à
            partir des principes actifs de certaines plantes combinés à leurs
            enzymes salivaires afin d'assainir leur logis. Pour nous, la
            propolis a de multiples vertus. Pendant l'Antiquité, les savants
            l'identifiaient déjà comme un bon antidouleur. À Rome, les soldats
            blessés recevaient de la propolis pour :
          </p>
          <ul>
            <li>arrêter une hémorragie</li>
            <li>
              accélérer la cicatrisation (<span>elle stimule la régénération, la croissance des cellules de la peau</span>
              ) et calmer la douleur (<span>elle a des propriétés anesthésiantes</span
              >)
            </li>
            <li>
              empêcher une infection, empêcher la propagation d'un champignon
              (<span>action antibactérienne, antivirale et antifongique</span>)
            </li>
            <li>
              écarter les bactéries et bloquer leur croissance
              (<span>antibiotique</span>)
            </li>
            <li>soulager les maladies respiratoires et assainir la bouche.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>

    <footer class="section">
      <a href="https://yanndev-art.fr" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Yann Cotard</a>
    </footer>

     
   
    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS :

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  /* background: #66ff33; */
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.webgl {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  outline: none;
}
/*-------------------NAVBAR-------------------------*/
nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2.5vh;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 12px 14px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.67);
  box-shadow: 0px 12px 14px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.67);
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #0191e4;
}

.left,
.right {
  font-size: clamp(1.5rem, 3vw, 2rem);
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2vw;
}

/*---------------FIN NAVBAR-------------------------*/

/*---------------HEADER-------------------------*/
header.section {
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 55vh;
}
h1 {
  font-family: "Rubik Mono One", sans-serif;
  color: #ffff6b;
  font-size: 14vw;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 4vw;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/*-------------------HEADER-------------------------*/

/*-------------------MAIN-------------------------*/
.section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .section {
    height: 70vh;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .section {
    height: 50vh;
  }
}

.even,
.odd {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 20vh auto;
}

.even,
.odd p {
  text-wrap: wrap;
}

.odd h3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.odd.text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-right: -20px;
}

.section h3 {
  font-family: "Bayon", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20vw;
  margin: 0 3vw;
}

.section h4 {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: clamp(1rem, 3vw, 2rem);
}

section p {
  font-size: clamp(1rem, 3vw, 2rem);
}

section img {
  width: clamp(30%, 40vw, 75%);
}

.intro {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 15vh;
}

.intro p {
  font-size: clamp(20px, 3vw, 30px);
  margin: 0 2vw;
}
.intro img {
  margin-left: -9px;
}

.text {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 0vw 0 4vw;
}

.rose {
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}

.pansy {
  margin-right: -20px;
}

.tournesol {
  width: clamp(30%, 30vw, 75%);
}

.shabeer {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin-left: -5vh;
  margin-top: 30vh;
}

ul li {
  font-size: clamp(1rem, 3vw, 2rem);
  margin-left: 5vw;
}

span {
  font-style: italic;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  font-size: clamp(0.8rem, 2vw, 1.5rem);
}

.section:last-child {
  height: 110vh;
}
/*-----------------FIN MAIN-------------------------*/
/*-----------------FOOTER-------------------------*/
footer.section {
  height: 25vh;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
a {
  font-family: "Rubik Mono One", sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: clamp(1rem, 3vw, 2rem);
  margin: 4vh 2vw;
}
/*-----------------FIN FOOTER-------------------------*/
```

JS

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";
import { DRACOLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader.js";

// Scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

//Loader environnement
const cubeTextureLoader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();

//Loader cube texture
const environmentMap = cubeTextureLoader.load([
  "static/environment/px.png",
  "static/environment/nx.png",
  "static/environment/py.png",
  "static/environment/ny.png",
  "static/environment/pz.png",
  "static/environment/nz.png",
]);

scene.environment = environmentMap;
scene.background = environmentMap;
scene.backgroundBlurriness = 0.2;
scene.backgroundIntensity = 0.3;

/**
 * Model
 */
//TODO instanciation du DRACOLoader AVANT le GLTFLoader
const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
dracoLoader.setDecoderPath("static/draco/");

const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
// console.log(gltfLoader);
gltfLoader.setDRACOLoader(dracoLoader);

let mixer = null;
let gltf = null;
let abeille;
gltfLoader.load(
  "http://127.0.0.1:5173/static/models/bee/flyingBee.gltf",
  (gltf) => {
    abeille =gltf.scene
    mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(gltf.scene);
    const action = mixer.clipAction(gltf.animations[0]);

    action.play();

    gltf.scene.scale.set(0.07, 0.07, 0.07);
  
  
    scene.add(abeille);
   
  }
);

// Tableau de positions de destination
const destinations = [
  { x: 102, y: 500, z:0 },
  { x: 623, y: 1700, z:0 },
  { x: 1394, y: 3200, z:0 },
  { x: 488, y: 4100, z:0 },
  { x: 1350, y: 5400, z:0 },
  { x: 437, y: 6625, z:0 },
  { x: 1521, y: 7925, z:0 },
  { x: 430, y: 9125, z:0 },
  { x: 524, y: 9747, z:0 },
];

// Créez les points de contrôle pour la courbe de Bézier
const points = [];

for (let i = 0; i < destinations.length; i++) {
  points.push(new THREE.Vector3(destinations[i].x, destinations[i].y, destinations[i].z,));
}
console.log(points)


// Créez la courbe de Bézier
const curve = new THREE.CubicBezierCurve3(
  points[2],
  points[4],
  points[6],
  points[8]
);

console.log(curve)

// Fonction pour mettre à jour la position de l'abeille le long de la courbe
function updateBeePosition() {
  
  const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
  const totalHeight = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight; // Utilisez la hauteur totale du contenu de la page
  // console.log(document.body.scrollHeight)
  // console.log(window.innerHeight)
  // console.log(totalHeight)
  // console.log(scrollPosition)
  // var y = window.scrollY
  // console.log(y)
  
  const t = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, scrollPosition / totalHeight));
  // Calculez le pourcentage de défilement
  console.log(t);

  // Ajoutez une condition pour gérer le cas où t est proche de zéro
   const threshold = 0.01; // Ajustez le seuil selon vos besoins

  if (abeille) {
    // console.log(abeille)
    if (t < threshold) {
      // Positionnez l'abeille en dehors de la vue de la caméra
      abeille.position.set(destinations[0].x, destinations[0].y, destinations[0].z);
      
    } else {
      // Obtenez la position sur la courbe à ce pourcentage
      const positionOnCurve = curve.getPointAt(t);
      console.log(positionOnCurve);

      // Mettez à jour la position de l'abeille
      abeille.position.copy(positionOnCurve);
       console.log(abeille.position.copy(positionOnCurve));
       console.log(abeille.position)
    }
  }
}
// Appelez la fonction initiale pour positionner l'abeille au chargement de la page
updateBeePosition();

window.requestAnimationFrame(updateBeePosition);

// Écoutez le défilement de la page pour mettre à jour la position de l'abeille
window.addEventListener("scroll", updateBeePosition);



// Canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas.webgl");

/**
 * Lights
 */
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 3);
scene.add(ambientLight);

const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 2);
directionalLight.castShadow = true;
directionalLight.shadow.mapSize.set(1024, 1024);
directionalLight.shadow.camera.far = 15;
directionalLight.shadow.camera.left = -7;
directionalLight.shadow.camera.top = 7;
directionalLight.shadow.camera.right = 7;
directionalLight.shadow.camera.bottom = -7;
directionalLight.position.set(5, 5, 5);
scene.add(directionalLight);

/**
 * Sizes
 */
const sizes = {
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
};

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  // Update sizes
  sizes.width = window.innerWidth;
  sizes.height = window.innerHeight;

  // Update camera
  camera.aspect = sizes.width / sizes.height;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  // Update renderer
  renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));
});

/**
 * Camera
 */
// Base camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  sizes.width / sizes.height,
  0.1,
  100
);
camera.position.set(0, 0.5, 3);
scene.add(camera);

/**
 * Renderer
 */
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: canvas,
});
renderer.outputColorSpace = THREE.LinearSRGBColorSpace;
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));

/**
 * Animate
 */
const clock = new THREE.Clock();
let previousTime = 0;

const tick = () => {
  const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime();
  const deltaTime = elapsedTime - previousTime;
  previousTime = elapsedTime;

  

  //Upadte mixer
  if (mixer !== null) {
    mixer.update(deltaTime);
  }
  // Render
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  // Call tick again on the next frame
  window.requestAnimationFrame(tick);
  
  
};

tick();
```

I tried everything. With or without a threshold or with a very low threshold.

With or without "window.requestAnimationFrame(updateBeePosition);" in the tick() function

And many other things I don’t remember so I tried options

the 3D object always disappears from the beginning of the vertical scroll

Someone to help me?